# IBM Watson's section 'Dialog' isn't working

Tags: chatbot, watson-conversation

[here image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJK2R.jpg)is anyone here using IBM Watson conversation ? Dialog section is it working for you ? even i tried with another account, it still doesn't working.
when i open my workspace i can navigate in 'intent' 'entities' but 'dialog' keep loading and doesn't  open 
I'll be thankful if anyone answer

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what is not working. Without proper info, we cannot help you

Comment: @Rinav i update the post for more info

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be because of network issues.Is it resolved or still the same?Please reply.

Comment: no it's not the network issue, it still not working and i didn't understand why